# Dict comprehension with additional key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dict comprehension that looks like this:

```py
bar = {
    n: n**2
    for n in range(1, 10)
}
```

Is there any way to add an additional key to the dict in the same expression? I was thinking of something like this:

```py
bar = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    n: n**2
    for n in range(1, 10)
}
```

This doesn't work though. How can I achieve this?
For now I am adding the additional entry manually afterwards but it would be good if I could do it in the same expression.

I know that the use case is not very clear from my example but in my actual code it would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python 3.9.0+, the `|` operator merges two dictionaries

```
bar = { 'foo': 'bar' } | {
    n: n**2
    for n in range(1, 10)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two operations, e.g.:

```
bar = {
    'foo': 'bar'
    }
bar.update( 
    {
        n: n**2
        for n in range(1, 10)
    }
)
print( f"{bar=}" )
```

result:

```
bar={'foo': 'bar', 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81}
```